# How object reference variable works?

Tags: c#, .net

While I was studying the .NET Reflection API, I came across the following code.

```
Assembly currentAssem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

I understood the code as below.

```
Assembly = Class Name   
currentAssem = object reference variable  
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly = Static method in Assembly class
```

But, I thought the object reference variable (in the stack) only holds the reference to the actual object (in the heap). I'm a bit confused why there is an object reference variable when there is no object created. Does the object reference variable hold the returned data from the method? Or something else?

When you create a variable for a class or struct, is it always an object reference variable? I mean you can do the following for assigning `2` to `a`.

```
int a = 2;
```

Can you do that for a class? Eg., if I have a class name of `Program` and I make a variable P - can I do the following?

```
Program P = 2;
```

Do I understand the following code correctly?

```
Program P = new Program();

P =  object reference variable   
new Program = It makes P point to an object of type Program
```

Comment: Which language is this?  Java?  C#?  It's not C.

Comment: "why there is object reference variable when there is no object created", currentAssem is actually an instance of the Assembly class so this object has been created

Comment: You can do "Program P = 2" if there is an implicit conversion operator from int to Program

Comment: "new Program()" only creates a new instance of Program, it's "P = new Program()", that stores the created object in a variable

Comment: I study c#. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets's consider your last code snippet first:

```
Program p = new Program();
```

`p` here is a `Program` reference variable. An `object` reference variable would be defined as:

```
object o = new Program();
```

As `Program` (and everything) inherits from `object`, you can assign an instance of `Program` to `o`.

Now consider this part of the line:

```
new Program()
```

This creates a new instance of the `Program` class. In the line of code `Program p = new Program();`, that reference is then assigned to `p`.

Now consider the following:

```
Program p1 = new Program();
Program p2 = p1;
```

Here, we are creating a new `Program` object and assigning a reference to it to `p1`. The next line then copies that reference into `p2`. So now both `p1` and `p2` refer to the same `Program` instance.

Finally, back to your fine code snippet:

```
Assembly currentAssem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

This is like our `Program p2 = p1;` line. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();` is a static method that returns a reference to an `Assembly` instance (in this case the assembly within which your code is running). The `Assembly currentAssem =` then copies that reference into `currentAssem`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx) link it tells us that `Assembly.getExecutingAssembly()` returns type `System.Reflection.Assembly`. (In `C#`, anyway).

So it makes sense that the reference to it is of type `Assembly` as the method returns a reference of that type.

David Arno made a great example of how it works:

```
Program P1 = new Program();
Program P2;
P2 = P1 // This step is exactly how the line containing the Assembly.getExecutingAssembly() method works.
```

And yes, you can still have an object reference variable not point to an object. You can later assign it to reference a certain object on the heap.

You cannot do (unless, of course, there is an implicit conversion as mentioned in the comments):

`Program P = 2;`

as 2 is not of type `Program` and does not extend `Program`.

For example, let's say your `Program` class had a method `getNameofProgram()`.

Could you do `P.getNameofProgram()`?

Of course not, doing `2.getNameofProgram()` makes no sense.

As for your last code snippet, you are slightly misunderstanding:

```
Program P = new Program();

Program P // Makes an Object reference Variable of type Program;
new Program() // Makes a new Instance of Program
= // Tells P to reference that Instance of the Program we just made
```

Answer (score 0):

C# (or any high level language) isn't really the best example to learn about stack vs heap and pointers...there's a lot of behind the scenes work that IMO complicates matters.

That said, I think you have it basically correct but are missing the fact that you can *copy* "object reference variables*. Since they are reference types, the two copies point to the same object on the heap.

So, in your first example, the static method `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` returns an object reference variable, that then gets copied to your `currentAssem` variable. There are now (at least) two variables pointing to the same location on the heap.

> When you create a variable for a class or struct, is it always an object reference variable?

No, structs are value types. When you create a variable for them, the variable contains the data - they do not point to the heap. Value types behave differently than reference types; when they are copied, the *contents* are copied and you get a brand new variable.

In your second example:

```
Program P = new Program();
```

It basically works like this:

```
P: create a location on the stack to store a memory address
new Program(): create a new Program instance on the heap
   return the address where it was created
=: copy the returned address into the location called "P"
```

There's of course more nuances around boxing, scoping, closures, etc. - but that's the basics.