# C# Unity - Assigning data to array containing classes - Thought I was doing it right

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity2D and coding in C#. I have a class 'TileInfoArray' which holds an array of 'TileInfo' classes. 'TileInfo' contains a bunch of data for the game's tilemap including what sprite should be shown, the movement cost, etc.

Sample of 'TileInfoArray':

```
   public class TileInfoArray {
         private TileInfo[] arr;
         . . .
        public void SetSprite(int index, Sprite sprite) {
            arr[index].sprite = sprite;
        }
    }
```

This code is called with a simple
'world.tileInfoArray.SetSprite(index, sprite_Cobblestone);', yet later when I call 'world.tileInfoArray[index].sprite' for that same index, I get the default sprite I used when I created the array.

```
tileInfoArray = new TileInfoArray(WorldSizeTiles);
tileInfoArray.Populate(new TileInfo());
```

If anyone was interested. 'Populate' just calls a for loop that adds starting data.

I'm confused as to why this is. I have verified that the indexes are always within range and mapped correctly, and the array starts with assigned default data. I'm aware that something like 'TileInfoArray array = world.tileInfoArray' would just copy the data, and trying 'array[index].sprite = newSprite' wouldn't affect the original 'world.tileInfoArray', but since I'm calling a method from the class that holds the array, shouldn't that then change its data?

Any help would be much appreciated. I will be out of town for the weekend, but I'll be back first thing Monday to answer any questions and hopefully just look like a big dummy for missing an obvious mistake.

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more code, you've shown how you created the array, but you havent shown or entirely explained where you changed the values to something else.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I fully understood your issue, and I'm also not sure about how deep you know the language to give any advice. Anyway, would you please add more code and try to better explain the problem? The basics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612431/how-object-reference-variable-works

Comment: in c# array=array does not copy data, it just changes the array reference

Comment: You call 'world.tileInfoArray.SetSprite(index, sprite_Cobblestone);' and modify world.tileInfoArray.arr[index] by that. Then you say you check 'world.tileInfoArray[index].sprite', not 'world.tileInfoArray.arr[index].sprite' to get the default sprite. Is this an error in the question or you really checked the wrong variable? Or do you also have an indexer implemented in TileInfoArray?